# Comparing 2 dates with python

Tags: python, datetimepicker

I need to compare 2 dates with a IF, but for some strange (:P) reason, I can't do it.
My code

```
date1 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
d2 = os.path.getmtime('/tmp/file')
date2 = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(d2)
if date1 == date2 :
    print 'same date'
else:
    print 'different date'
```

I don't know why, show with a print the same date, but, with this IF shows 'different date'
Maybe is a newbie question, sorry !

Thank you !

Comment: Same VARS shows the same values, If I print date1 and date 2, have this:
2011-12-30
2011-12-30

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`date1` is a string, and `date2` is a `datetime.date`. Perhaps you meant `date1 = datetime.date.today()`.

Answer (score 2):

- `time.strftime` returns an object of type `str` (a "string")
- `datetime.date.fromtimestamp` returns an object of type `datetime.date`

So `date1` and `date2` will be objects of different types.
Comparing to objects of different types will *always* yield `False` (this is an aspect of [strong typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing))

Comment: How can I compare these vars? or pass the datetime value to a string?

Comment: @Cirux: Instead of using `strftime`, you can get the current day as a `datetime.date` object by calling [`datetime.date.today`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today).